# Can I update a jS variable's property dynamically from another variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scroll, properties

I'm trying to update a property of a jS variable using the scroll velocity which I'm storing in another variable. This is my code thus far (scroll to the second code box as the first part works correctly):

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('main').attr('id', 'grained');

  (function (window, doc) {

      "use strict";

      function grained(ele, opt) {

          var element = null,
              elementId = null,
              selectorElement = null;

          if (typeof ele === 'string') {
              element = doc.getElementById(ele.split('#')[1]);
          }

          if (!element) {
              console.error('Grained: cannot find the element with id ' + ele);
              return;
          } else {
              elementId = element.id;
          }

          //set style for parent
          if (element.style.position !== 'absolute') {
              element.style.position = 'relative';
          }
          element.style.overflow = 'hidden';

          var prefixes = ["", "-moz-", "-o-animation-", "-webkit-", "-ms-"];

          //default option values
          var options = {
              animate: true,
              patternWidth: 100,
              patternHeight: 100,
              grainOpacity: 0.1,
              grainDensity: 1,
              grainWidth: 1,
              grainHeight: 1,
              grainChaos: 0.5,
              grainSpeed: 20

          };

          Object.keys(opt).forEach(function (key) {
              options[key] = opt[key];
          });


          var generateNoise = function () {
              var canvas = doc.createElement('canvas');
              var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
              canvas.width = options.patternWidth;
              canvas.height = options.patternHeight;
              for (var w = 0; w < options.patternWidth; w += options.grainDensity) {
                  for (var h = 0; h < options.patternHeight; h += options.grainDensity) {
                      var rgb = Math.random() * 256 | 0;
                      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + [rgb, rgb, rgb, options.grainOpacity].join() + ')';
                      ctx.fillRect(w, h, options.grainWidth, options.grainHeight);
                  }
              }
              return canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
          };

          function addCSSRule(sheet, selector, rules, index) {
              var ins = '';
              if (selector.length) {
                  ins = selector + "{" + rules + "}";
              } else {
                  ins = rules;
              }

              if ("insertRule" in sheet) {
                  sheet.insertRule(ins, index);
              } else if ("addRule" in sheet) {
                  sheet.addRule(selector, rules, index);
              }
          }


          var noise = generateNoise();

          var animation = '',
              keyFrames = ['0%:-10%,10%', '10%:-25%,0%', '20%:-30%,10%', '30%:-30%,30%', '40%::-20%,20%', '50%:-15%,10%', '60%:-20%,20%', '70%:-5%,20%', '80%:-25%,5%', '90%:-30%,25%', '100%:-10%,10%'];

          var pre = prefixes.length;
          while (pre--) {
              animation += '@' + prefixes[pre] + 'keyframes grained{';
              for (var key = 0; key < keyFrames.length; key++) {
                  var keyVal = keyFrames[key].split(':');
                  animation += keyVal[0] + '{';
                  animation += prefixes[pre] + 'transform:translate(' + keyVal[1] + ');';
                  animation += '}';
              }
              animation += '}';
          }

          //add animation keyframe
          var animationAdded = doc.getElementById('grained-animation');
          if (animationAdded) {
              animationAdded.parentElement.removeChild(animationAdded);
          }
          var style = doc.createElement("style");
          style.type = "text/css";
          style.id = 'grained-animation';
          style.innerHTML = animation;
          doc.body.appendChild(style);

          //add custimozed style
          var styleAdded = doc.getElementById('grained-animation-' + elementId);
          if (styleAdded) {
              styleAdded.parentElement.removeChild(styleAdded);
          }

          style = doc.createElement("style");
          style.type = "text/css";
          style.id = 'grained-animation-' + elementId;
          doc.body.appendChild(style);

          var rule = 'background-image: url(' + noise + ');';
          rule += 'position: absolute;content: "";height: 300%;width: 300%;left: -100%;top: -100%;';
          pre = prefixes.length;
          if (options.animate) {
              while (pre--) {
                  rule += prefixes[pre] + 'animation-name:grained;';
                  rule += prefixes[pre] + 'animation-iteration-count: infinite;';
                  rule += prefixes[pre] + 'animation-duration: ' + options.grainChaos + 's;';
                  rule += prefixes[pre] + 'animation-timing-function: steps(' +options.grainSpeed + ', end);';
              }
          }

          //selecter element to add grains
          selectorElement = '#' + elementId + '::before';


          addCSSRule(style.sheet, selectorElement, rule);


      }

      window.grained = grained;
      //END
  })(window, document);
```

// Here down is the important part //

```
   var grainOptions = {
           animate: true,
           patternWidth: 100,
           patternHeight: 100,
           grainOpacity: 0.04,
           grainDensity: 1,
           grainWidth: 1,
           grainHeight: 1
   };

    grained('#grained', grainOptions);
  
    document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("wheel", scrollGlitch);

    function scrollGlitch(event) {
      var y = event.deltaY;
      var scaleY = y;
      var divider = 100;
      var sum = scaleY / divider;
      console.log(sum);
    }
});
```

From this I am getting 2 things which I need:

- the property value of `grainOpacity`;
- the scroll velocity as stored in the variable `sum` (which is divided by 100 to make the values the right scale i.e 0.01 - 0.1;

What I need to do now is update the `grainOpacity` property of the `grainOptions` variable with the value of the `sum` variable. Is this possible? How would I achieve this, I read about Bracket/Dot notations but can't tell if this is the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take any object field reference using dot like

> grainOptions.grainOpacity

Then you can redefine field value as using `let` variables.
Update your scrollGlitch function:

```
function scrollGlitch(event) {
  var y = event.deltaY;
  var scaleY = y;
  var divider = 100;
  var sum = scaleY / divider;
  grainOptions.grainOpacity = sum;
}
```

Note. In JS you can take Object fields' value with 2 ways:

1. With saving reference on field to update it's own value. Ex:

> grainOptions.grainOpacity.

2. Only for take value. Ex:

> grainOptions['grainOpacity']